# Inclusion of weights in linear mixed effects model drastically changes the random effect variance estimate in lme

Tags: lme4-nlme

I am fitting a linear mixed effects model in using `lme`. Currently, I am investigating two different version of the model. For both versions, I include a spatial correlation structure using an exponential covariance model. However, after observing heteroskedasticity, I introduced a variance model to attempt to correct the issue.

The first model, with the variance model is:

```
Linear mixed-effects model fit by REML
 Data: segs 
      AIC     BIC   logLik
  8056.84 8079.48 -4023.42

Random effects:
 Formula: ~1 | STAND
        (Intercept) Residual
StdDev: 0.004029632 9.137936

Correlation Structure: Exponential spatial correlation
 Formula: ~centr_x + centr_y | STAND 
 Parameter estimate(s):
   range 
5.162046 
Variance function:
 Structure: Power of variance covariate
 Formula: ~mean_z_sq 
 Parameter estimates:
power 
  0.5 
Fixed effects: CVTS_ha ~ mean_z_sq 
                Value Std.Error  DF  t-value p-value
(Intercept) 0.5832954 2.6531622 651  0.21985  0.8261
mean_z_sq   1.1919768 0.0293856 651 40.56329  0.0000
 Correlation: 
          (Intr)
mean_z_sq -0.209

Standardized Within-Group Residuals:
         Min           Q1          Med           Q3          Max 
-2.942655368 -0.414073769  0.006292279  0.503525231  4.465095404 

Number of Observations: 686
Number of Groups: 34
```

The second model, without the variance model is:

```
Linear mixed-effects model fit by REML
 Data: segs 
       AIC      BIC    logLik
  8962.991 8985.631 -4476.495

Random effects:
 Formula: ~1 | STAND
        (Intercept) Residual
StdDev:    82.25245 176.9502

Correlation Structure: Exponential spatial correlation
 Formula: ~centr_x + centr_y | STAND 
 Parameter estimate(s):
   range 
4.921083 
Fixed effects: CVTS_ha ~ mean_z_sq 
                Value Std.Error  DF   t-value p-value
(Intercept) -31.75715  27.52167 651 -1.153896   0.249
mean_z_sq     1.25656   0.04866 651 25.823016   0.000
 Correlation: 
          (Intr)
mean_z_sq -0.72 

Standardized Within-Group Residuals:
        Min          Q1         Med          Q3         Max 
-3.10883353 -0.29731966  0.03397372  0.27536462  4.90265331 

Number of Observations: 686
Number of Groups: 34
```

Some details:

The dataset consists of sampling units that are nested by STAND. The sampling units also tend to be spatially clustered (i.e. in clusters of 1-15 sampling units, all within 20 meters or so of eachother).

As can be seen, the estimation of the variance of the intercept (and residual) drastically changes between the two models. Is this reasonable behavior? My fear is that the first model may have biased variance component estimates, but I cannot easily reason why this may be the case.

Comment: I may be misreading the outputs, but it looks to me like the first one has the variance model and the second does not, *contra* the text immediately above the two.

Comment: Can you include in your post the actual model calls you used so we don't have to wade through the output to figure that out?